# TortoiseSVN - creating a patch with externals

Tags: tortoisesvn, svn-externals

I have fairly complex projects using SVN with externals. Also, I am using TortoiseSVN 1.8.4  Build 24972 - 64 Bit , 2013/11/24 11:15:39 + Subversion 1.8.5, -release.
I can see the overlay icon of the "modified" status on the cehcked out copy's root, but if I try creating a patch using TortoiseSVN, it does not show any modified files. Is this a bug or am I doing something stupid?
Thanks
Marco

Comment: Where are you trying to create the patch? Commands like this do not recurse into externals, I think.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already feared this was the answer. I have a repository that does no contain any actual file, only externals that collect the code I need for a specific card. So, there are different "pools" of drivers (depending on an "export license" classification). Depending on those needed by a project, we create a repository that links together the required drivers. The "root" of the repository is where I try to create a patch, so, if Tortoise "create a patch" command does not follow externals, it won't work. Pity, as the "Check for Modifications" does work correctly ...

Comment: Can you create the patch from the check for modifications dialog, by selecting everything that is modified and right-clicking, for the unified diff? I haven't tried that for externals, myself.

Comment: Ben! Thanks very much! That worked ... You indeed select all changed files (or those you want a patch for) from the pane of the modified files and right click. Thanks again.

Comment: Wow, I almost did not expect that to work. I'll make it an answer...

Answer (score 0):

Try launching the "check for modifications" dialog. From there, select all modified files. Right click on a selected file, and view the unified diff. You should be able to save that as a patch. But you may need an external command to apply the patch.